# Passing active Powershell PSSession connection as argument in Start-Job

Tags: powershell, office365

I am writing a script which gathers data from Exchange Online concerning mailbox permissions for each mailbox in our organization. To do this I gather all mailbox data into a variable then I use foreach to iterate through each mailbox and check the mailbox permissions applied to it. This takes time when you are working with over 15000 mailboxes.

I would like to use Powershell Jobs to speed this process up by having multiple jobs checking permissions and appending them to a single CSV file. Is there a way to pass an active PSSession into a new job so that the job "shares" the active session of the parent process that spawned the job and does not require a new one to be established?

I could place a New-PSSession call into the function but Microsoft has active session limits in Exchange Online PSSessions so it would limit the number of jobs I could have running at one time to 3. The rest would have to be queued through a while loop. If I can share a single session between multiple jobs I would be limited by computer resources rather than connection restrictions.

Has anyone successfully passed an active PSSession through to a job before?

Edit:

I've been working on using runspaces to try to accomplish this with Boe Prox's PoshRSJobs module. Still having some difficulty getting it to work properly. Doesn't create the CSV or append to it but only if I try to sort out the permissions within the foreach statement. The `Write-Output` inside the scriptblock only outputs the implicit remoting information too which is odd.

Code is below.

```
Connect-ToOffice365TenantPSSession

$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize 10 -IncludeInactiveMailbox

$indexCount = 1

foreach ($mailbox in $mailboxes) {
$script = @"
`$cred = Import-Clixml -Path 'C:\Users\Foo\.credentials\StoredLocalCreds.xml'

`$o365Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential `$cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession `$o365Session -CommandName @('Get-Mailbox','Get-MailboxPermission')

`$internal_mailbox = `$Using:mailbox
`$mailboxPermissions = `$internal_mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission

foreach (`$permission in (`$mailboxPermissions | Where-Object {`$_.User -match 'tenantName|companyDomain'}))
{
    `$userPermissions = `$permission | Select-Object Identity, User, AccessRights

    `$permissionObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
        "MailboxName" = `$userPermissions.Identity
        "MailboxAddress" = `$internal_mailbox.PrimarySmtpAddress
        "MailboxType" = `$internal_mailbox.RecipientTypeDetails
        "UserWithAccess" = `$userPermissions.User
        "AccessRights" = `$userPermissions.AccessRights
    }

    if (Test-Path 'C:\Scripts\MailboxPermissions.csv') {
        `$permissionObject | Export-Csv 'C:\Scripts\MailboxPermissions.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append
    } else {
        New-Item -Path 'C:\Scripts\MailboxPermissions.csv'
        `$permissionObject | Export-Csv 'C:\Scripts\MailboxPermissions.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }

    Write-Output `$permissionObject
}
"@

    $scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($script)

    $continue = $false

    do
    {
        if ((Get-RSJob | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Running"}).count -lt 3) {
            Start-RSJob -Name "Mailbox $indexCount" -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock

            $indexCount++
            $continue = $true
        }
        else {
            Start-Sleep 1
        }
    } while ($continue -eq $false)
}

Get-RSJob | Receive-RSJob
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specifications here, but you are not showing code and yet, asking for an opinion.

That is, as many would say here, off topic, because the goal here is to assist with code that is not working or the like. So, at this point, have you tried what you are asking, and if so, what happened?

So, IMHO … Yet, since you are here. let's not send you away empty handed.

[As per a similar ask here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/e5730d3a-2076-40ba-838e-bf4fbafcde93/cant-access-pssession-from-background-job), the accepted answer delivered was...

> … you have a current PSSession opened up on your console and then you
>   are attempting to use that same session in a background job. This will
>   not work because you are using two different PowerShell processes and
>   are unable to share the live data between the runspaces as it is
>   deserialized and loses all of its capabilities. You will need to look
>   at creating your own PowerShell runspaces if your goal is to share
>   live variables across multiple PowerShell sessions.

Even with the above, you still have those consumption limits you mention and technically based on your use case, you'd more than likely end up with serious performance issues as well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I've added some code to the OP with some attempts to do what I was talking about.